# Laravel - Form only submitting data from one section in blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two sections included in one view file that I am working out of and they are the sidebar and content sections. I ran into a rather confusing issue, being that both sections contain data that I want submitted via the form.

For some reason, the view is only rendering the form across the content section and excluding all of the data from the sidebar section. Originally I thought opening the form at the top of the content section and closing it at the end of the sidebar section would work. Unfortunately that was not the case and I'm at a loss.

I was wondering if there was any way possible to extend the form so it includes the data across both sections? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', 'Sign Up')

@section('content')
  {!! Form::open(['route' => 'signup.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
  <div class="panel-header"><span>{{ $visitor->username }}'s Profile</span></div>
  <div class="secondary-panel" align="center"><strong>Player Information</strong></div>
  <div class="xbs-border"></div>
  <div class="row_1g">
    <div class="body-content">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('first', 'First Name') }}
          {{ Form::text('first', $player->first, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('last', 'Last Name') }}
          {{ Form::text('last', $player->last, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('number', 'Number') }}
          {{ Form::selectRange('number', 0, 99, $player->num, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('birthday', 'Birthday') }}
          {{ Form::date('birthday', $player->birthday, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('city', 'City') }}
          {{ Form::text('city', $player->city, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'City')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('state_province', 'State/Province') }}
          {{ Form::select('state_province',['United States' => ['' => 'State/Province', 'AL'=>'Alabama','AK'=>'Alaska','AZ'=>'Arizona','AR'=>'Arkansas','CA'=>'California','CO'=>'Colorado','CT'=>'Connecticut','DE'=>'Delaware','DC'=>'District of Columbia','FL'=>'Florida','GA'=>'Georgia','HI'=>'Hawaii','ID'=>'Idaho','IL'=>'Illinois','IN'=>'Indiana','IA'=>'Iowa','KS'=>'Kansas','KY'=>'Kentucky','LA'=>'Louisiana','ME'=>'Maine','MD'=>'Maryland','MA'=>'Massachusetts','MI'=>'Michigan','MN'=>'Minnesota','MS'=>'Mississippi','MO'=>'Missouri','MT'=>'Montana','NE'=>'Nebraska','NV'=>'Nevada','NH'=>'New Hampshire','NJ'=>'New Jersey','NM'=>'New Mexico','NY'=>'New York','NC'=>'North Carolina','ND'=>'North Dakota','OH'=>'Ohio','OK'=>'Oklahoma','OR'=>'Oregon','PA'=>'Pennsylvania','RI'=>'Rhode Island','SC'=>'South Carolina','SD'=>'South Dakota','TN'=>'Tennessee','TX'=>'Texas','UT'=>'Utah','VT'=>'Vermont','VA'=>'Virginia','WA'=>'Washington','WV'=>'West Virginia','WI'=>'Wisconsin','WY'=>'Wyoming',], 'Canada' => ['AB' => 'Alberta', 'BC' => 'British Columbia', 'MB' => 'Manitoba', 'NB' => 'New Brunswick', 'NL' => 'Newfoundland', 'NS' => 'Nova Scotia', 'NT' => 'Northwest Territories', 'NU' => 'Nunavut', 'ON' => 'Ontario', 'PE' => 'Prince Edward Island', 'QC' => 'Quebec', 'SK' => 'Saskatchewan', 'YT' => 'Yukon']], $player->state_province, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1f" style="text-align:center;border-top:1px solid #ddd;">
      <div class="body-content">
        <strong>Player name falls under the site terms and conditions.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-header"><span>Additional Information</span></div>
  <div class="secondary-panel" align="center"><strong>Player Availability</strong></div>
  <div class="xbs-border"></div>
  <div class="row_1g">
    <div class="body-content">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('time', 'Preferred Time (EST)') }}
          {{ Form::select('time', ['9' => '9:00 PM', '10' => '10:00 PM', '11' => '11:00 PM'], $player->time, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('commitment', 'League Commitment') }}
          {{ Form::select('commitment', ['0' => 'Part-Time', '1' => 'Full-Time',], $player->commitment, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ Form::label('available_extra', 'Availability Extra') }}
          {{ Form::textarea('available_extra', $player->available_extra, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Any additional information that you would like to add.')) }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_1g">
    <div class="body-content">
      <div class="form-group" align="center">
        {!! Form::hidden('player_id', $visitor->user_id) !!}
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Registration', array('class' => 'btn xbs-button')) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row_1f" style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;">
    <div class="body-content">
      <ul style="margin-bottom:0;">
        <li><strong>Part-Time Player</strong> - At least two games per week.</li>
        <li><strong>Full-Time Player</strong> - Anything over two games games per week.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
  <div class="panel-header"><span>Position Preferences</span></div>
  <div class="secondary-panel" align="center"><strong>Position Breakdown</strong></div>
  <div class="xbs-border"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
    <div class="row_1g">
      <div class="body-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_c', 'Center') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_c', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_lw', 'Left Wing') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_lw', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_rw', 'Right Wing') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_rw', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_ld', 'Left Defense') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_ld', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_rd', 'Right Defense') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_rd', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('pos_g', 'Goalie') }}
            {{ Form::select('pos_g', ['0' => 'Never', '1' => 'Rarely', '2' => 'Occasional', '3' => 'Preferred'], null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_1f" style="border-top:1px solid #ddd;">
      <div class="body-content">
        <ul style="margin-bottom:0;">
          <li><strong>Never</strong> - 0 games per season.</li>
          <li><strong>Rarely</strong> - up to 10 games per season.</li>
          <li><strong>Occasional</strong> - 10 to 20 games per season.</li>
          <li><strong>Preferred</strong> - Any amount of games.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

**Main.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @include('partials._header')
    @yield('stylesheets')
</head>

<body>

  @include('partials._navigation')

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0;margin-top:20px;">
      @include('partials._messages')
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;">
      @yield('sidebar')
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-right:0;">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </div>

  @include('partials._footer')

  @include('partials._javascript')

  @yield('scripts')
```

Comment: What does `main.blade.php` look like? It's most likely that you're `@yield`ing the sections inside other HTML elements, which results in the `<form>` tags being incorrectly nested in different parents.

Comment: @fubar That is a good point. I've added my main.blade.php file to the original post. Would there be anyway to organize it in a similar fashion but still have the form take in both sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is in your `main.blade.php` file.

This markup will cause a browser to try and fix your form, because the opening and closing form element do not share the same parent.

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;">
    @yield('sidebar')
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-right:0;">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

This would most likely result in a form in the content section and no form in the sidebar section. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;">
    <form>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-right:0;">
    ...
</div>
```

You need to either wrap your columns with the form element, or move the column divs into your sections.

```
@section('content')
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'signup.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-right:0;">
            ...
        </div>
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;">
            ...
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```